# How can I apply Bold to CJK Languages in Lualatex?

Tags: luatex

I am trying to add bold to CJK languages but no formatting is applied

My implementation to support CJK language is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand{\cvspace}{\vskip 1.2em}\directlua{
\directlua {
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk",
      {
        Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR:mode=harf;script=hang;",
        Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC:mode=harf;script=hani;",
        Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=kana;",
        Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=hira;",
      }
    )
  }
}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={multiscript=cjk}]{Linux Libertine O}



\begin{document}

\textbf{Japanese: 読サ統転ン務6危キリイ日記属して帯} \\

\bf{Chinese: 关于数学部分关于数学部分关于数} \\

Korean: 헌법재판소에서법률의위헌결정,헌법재판소 \\

\end{document}
```

If I apply bold to a CJK language using either `\textbf{}` or `\bf{}`, the text is shown but without any boldness, so there are no formatting changes made.
[image]

How can I apply boldness to CJK languages with this implementation?

Comment: note that `\bf` applies to the rest of the document if used as you have it, the syntax (if you choose to use this legacy command) would be `{\bf` not `\bf{`

Comment: Ah, thank you, note taken. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve my issue :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the `multiscript` feature operates at a rather low level, it doesn't automatically react to the bold setting. You can do this manually by adding a separate multiscript specification for bold fonts. For any font specified by fontname (e.g. "Noto Serif CJK KR") you can select the corresponding bold font by appending "/B". So you get

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand{\cvspace}{\vskip 1.2em}
\directlua {
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk", {
    Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR:mode=harf;script=hang;",
    Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC:mode=harf;script=hani;",
    Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=kana;",
    Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=hira;",
  })
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk_bold", {
    Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR/B:mode=harf;script=hang;",
    Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC/B:mode=harf;script=hani;",
    Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP/B:mode=harf;script=kana;",
    Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP/B:mode=harf;script=hira;",
  })
}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={multiscript=cjk},BoldFeatures={RawFeature={multiscript=cjk_bold}}]{Linux Libertine O}



\begin{document}

\textbf{Japanese: 読サ統転ン務6危キリイ日記属して帯} \\

{\bfseries Chinese: 关于数学部分关于数学部分关于数} \\

Korean: 헌법재판소에서법률의위헌결정,헌법재판소 \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, you are a legend thank you, I suspect it would be something like that but I wasn't sure how to put it together. Thank you.